# Receive only first line when using mysql SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

```
/**
 * @param string $nick
 * @return array|null
 */
public function getPlayerByNick(string $nick) : ?array{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM reports";
    $result = $this->connection->query($query);
    if($result instanceof \mysqli_result){
        $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $result->free();
        var_dump($data);
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I do var_dump I get only first user in the table, but I want to get them all. How can I do that?

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: You have to loop through the rows to get each row. Your line ```$data = $result->fetch_assoc();``` is loading only one row if the results.

Comment: Try `while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`. `$nick` doesn't seem to be being used though, is this just a simple example?

Comment: See the examples in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hopefully this your help

```
/**
 * @param string $nick
 * @return array|null
 */

   public function getPlayerByNick(string $nick) : ?array{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM reports";
    $result = $this->connection->query($query);
    if($result instanceof \mysqli_result){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["nick"]);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * @param string $nick
 * @return array|null
 */
public function getPlayerByNick(string $nick) : ?array{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM reports";
    $result = $this->connection->query($query);
    if($result instanceof \mysqli_result){
        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
          var_dump($data);
      }
      $result->free();
    }
    return null;
}
```